# delete capitalized items from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have an NSArray that contains a bunch of strings. Some of the items in the NSArray are capitalized; some are not. I want to delete all of the items that are capitalized from the NSArray.

My code is below. If you have a mac, you can run this code, since all macs come loaded with the file I am loading into the NSArray.

```
// Read in a file as a huge string (ignoring the possibility of an error)
        NSString *wordString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/usr/share/dict/words" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
// Break it into an array of strings
        NSArray *words = [wordString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

for example, if my NSArray contains the following two items `['wolf','Wolf']` I want `Wolf` to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. Not necessarily the best/fastest:

```
NSCharacterSet *uppercaseSet = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];
NSMutableArray *itemsToDelete = [NSMutableArray new];
for ( NSString *word in words ) {
  if ( (word.length > 0) && [uppercaseSet characterIsMember:[word characterAtIndex:0]] )
     [itemsToDelete addObject:word];
}

 NSMutableArray *newArray = [words mutableCopy];
 [newArray removeObjectsInArray:itemsToDelete];
```

After looking at the code above, I realized the code below would be much faster. Turns out to be about 40x faster because it's not deleting items from an array, just appending them, which is a faster operation:

```
NSCharacterSet *uppercaseSet = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:words.count];

for ( NSString *word in words ) {
  if ( (word.length > 0) && ![uppercaseSet characterIsMember:[word characterAtIndex:0]] )
     [newArray addObject:word];
}
```

Comment: I got the following error: `Initializing 'NSArray *_strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'`

Comment: saw your edit and implemented that instead. thanks again for all of your help.